# JavaScript Post Request w/ Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, image, input

I'm afraid I might know the answer to this already. I'm hoping to present an HTML5 form offline in which a user can select an Image to upload. Once the user gets back on line the image will be uploaded. I can extract all the data from the file input, but is there a way to send the data via post to save the blob on the server?

I'm using jQuery and have a Rails backend (typical fileuploads are handled through CarrierWave).

Answer (score 1):

You can create `online` event and call `submit()` on form that has your file image.

- http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml
- http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: The user needs to leave to page (or add multiple entries), so the form really needs to be preprocessed by JS and then posted later.

Comment: Do the same as AJAX Uploading scripts (https://github.com/valums/ajax-upload), but instead upload instantly do this later. Uploading scripts use file input filed on top of button, so when you click a button you click file input filed inside iframe. You can do the same but after you add one file you add another filed (changing CSS position), and when user is back on-line you upload them all with submit.

Comment: You can use array as field names, http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/use-arrays-with-html-form-inputs, If user is offline just add another input fileds for all variables like `<input name="name[]" /><input name="email[]" />` to the form and hide those that was inserted before. If you do that in this way your server code will not change it will always get array of `names` and `emails` (with one entry or multiple entries if user goes off-line).