# Saving javascript edited image with php

Tags: php, javascript, pixastic, image-editing

I've been looking at this js image processing library, [pixastic.com](http://pixastic.com).
How can I save the new image with php? Is it even possible?

Comment: no, if the image is processed client side (js) php (server-side) has no access.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: apparently theres a `getImageData()` function in HTML5 that returns raw pixel information
you could pass that and rework it with gd?

Comment: I guess I'll have to wait till html5 enabled browsers are the norm.

Comment: if the functionality doesn't exist in the browser, pop up a message explaining that they need to use a compliant browser to enable that feature, then suggest a few.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try posting the image from the client to the server using JavaScript.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265998/javascript-post-request-w-image) is a SO question which could help you do so.